# ATM transaction behavior with denomination of an amount in php

Tags: php, class, currency

Php Class which can replicate ATM transaction behavior.

> Assume that we have 50,000 cash available in ATM and we need to
>   dispense money in 100,500 and 1000 rupee notes.
>
> lets take an example if amount is 5000 then show
>
> 1000 * 4
>
> 500  *  1
>
> 100  * 5

here is my code

```
<html>
<body>
  <center>
    <h2>Atm Machine</h2>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
      <input type="text" name="txtAmount" placeholder="Enter Amount" required>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
    </form>
  <?php
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        $message = "";
        class AtmBehavior{

          public function atmDispencer($amount){
            if($amount != ""){
              // //$amount= intval($amount);
              $notes = array(1000,500,100);
              $noteCount = array(0,0,0);
              $output="";

              if($amount <=0)
              {
                $output="<b>Invalid Amount</b>";
                return $output;
              }
              elseif ($amount > 50000) {
                 $output="<b>Amount should not exceed 50k</b>";
                 return $output;
              }
              else{
                if(!preg_match('/\d\d[0]$/',$amount))
                {
                  $output="<b>Invalid Amount</b>";
                  return $output;
                }else{
                  for($i=0;$i<count($notes);$i++){
                    if($notes[$i]<$amount || $notes[$i]==$amount){
                      $noteCount[$i]=intval($amount/$notes[$i]);
                      $amount=$amount-$noteCount[$i]*$notes[$i];
                      //$amount=$amount%$notes[$i];
                    }
                  }
                  for($i=0;$i<count($noteCount);$i++){
                    if($noteCount[$i]!=0){
                      $output .= "<br><b>".$notes[$i]." X ".$noteCount[$i]." = ".($notes[$i]*$noteCount[$i])."</b>";
                    }
                  }
                      return $output;
                }
              }
            }else{
              $output="<b>Invalid Amount- Amount Input Not Blank</b>";
              return $output;
            }
        }
    }
    $transaction = new AtmBehavior;
    $message = $transaction->atmDispencer($_POST['txtAmount']);
  ?>
  <div><br>
  <?php
    echo "Output: $message";
  }
  ?>
  </div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

if i pass 5000 as an amount it gives me output like this

1000 * 5 = 5000

but output what i need is

> 1000 * 4 = 4000
>
> 500 * 1 = 500
>
> 100 * 5 = 500

please help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: How should the code know what kind of bills to "print"? Did your teacher tell you more specific how to split the numbers?

Comment: What is this? `if(!preg_match('/\d\d[0]$/',$amount))`

Comment: need to split the amount in multiple denominations like actual ATM

Comment: None of the ATMs that I have ever used has done anything like that. So please explain what you want the code to do

Comment: i want a code that runs exactly like an atm.

Comment: @php pirate have a look at your question `runs exactly like an ATM` an atm machine does not show multiple inaccurate values in different denominations unless there is one which am not aware of. If your input amount is 5000 how then do you arrive at `4000` `500` `500` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 echo 'Atm is on<br>';

 //amount to be withdrawn
 $amount=5000;

 //when a set of denomination is available indicate
 /*denomination sets which are available are indicated by true*/
 $one_thousands=true;
 $five_hundreds=true;
 $one_hundreds=false;

 //check if amount to be withdrawn is a multiple of 100
 if(($amount % 100)==0)
 {
  if($one_thousands==true && $five_hundreds==true && $one_hundreds==true)
  {
    //check if amount is divisible by 1000 or by 500 else divide by 100 and remit cash
    if($amount%1000==0)
    {
      $number_to_print = $amount/1000;
      $currency_denomination = 'one_thousands';
      echo "".$number_to_print." of ".$currency_denomination."";
    }
    elseif($amount%500==0)
    {
      $number_to_print = $amount/500;
      $currency_denomination = 'five_hundreds';
      echo "".$number_to_print." of ".$currency_denomination."";
    }
    else
    {
      $number_to_print = $amount/100;
      $currency_denomination = 'one_hundreds';
      echo "".$number_to_print." of ".$currency_denomination."";
    }
   }
   elseif($one_thousands!=true && $five_hundreds==true && $one_hundreds==true)
   {
     if($amount%500==0)
     {
       $number_to_print = $amount/500;
       $currency_denomination = 'five_hundreds';
       echo "".$number_to_print." of ".$currency_denomination."";
     }
     else
     {
       $number_to_print = $amount/100;
       $currency_denomination = 'one_hundreds';
       echo "".$number_to_print." of ".$currency_denomination."";
     }
   }
   elseif($one_thousands==true && $five_hundreds!=true && $one_hundreds==true)
   {
     if($amount%1000==0)
     {
       $number_to_print = $amount/1000;
       $currency_denomination = 'one_thousands';
       echo "".$number_to_print." of ".$currency_denomination."";
     }
     else
     {
       $number_to_print = $amount/100;
       $currency_denomination = 'one_hundreds';
       echo "".$number_to_print." of ".$currency_denomination."";
     }
   }
   elseif($one_thousands==true && $five_hundreds==true && $one_hundreds!=true)
   {
     if($amount%1000==0)
     {
       $number_to_print = $amount/1000;
       $currency_denomination = 'one_thousands';
       echo "".$number_to_print." of ".$currency_denomination."";
     }
     elseif($amount%500==0)
     {
       $number_to_print = $amount/500;
       $currency_denomination = 'five_hundreds';
       echo "".$number_to_print." of ".$currency_denomination."";
     }
     else
     {
       echo'enter an amount in multiples of 1000 or 500';
     }
   }
   /*they are 4 other instances, add that to complete the logic*/
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Output what I need is denomination with each currency available in set not only in single currency

Comment: Thats exactly what the code shows `$number_to_print` is the number of currency to print out. `$currency_denomination` is the set of currency available and to be printed.